# Server side redirect vs Javascript redirect in terms of SEO

Tags: http, url, seo, server-side

I am creating my own short url website 9o9.in

While a visitor hits a short url generated by my site, he will essentially hit my server first. But I know there might be several links of potentially harmful or inappropriate sites which will be shortened using my site's service.

In order to make sure that I am not not setting a negative reputation of my site in terms of SEO, by linking or http referring unaccepted sites in the eyes of a Search Engine, should I go for a server side redirect like using php header() function, or shall I do a javascript based client side redirect?

Well, I know the wiser solution is to prevent users from generating short links of unacceptable sites. But right now I can't afford to implement it, as it would require extensive amount of data analysis or using expensive word filtering APIs...

Any help is highly appretiated.

Thanks.

Comment: Take care: with offering such a service where unknown users can post links freely, you will be held responsible for the links in most contries on earth. Meaning you may get into legal problems.

Answer (score 1):

A server-side redirect will be lower latency, as the browser can immediately begin fetching the new page whereas, with a client-side redirect in JavaScript, the browser must continue downloading your JavaScript code and then must execute this JavaScript code. Therefore, it is in your users' best interest to use a server-side redirect wherever possible over doing client-side redirecting. And, because it is in the users' best interest, it is also in a search engine's best interest to reward such behavior (indeed, Google has publicly stated that end user latency is one of many ranking signals that is used).

On the subject, though, you may want to take advantage of the [safe browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) to help you validate the URLs to which you redirect for malware, so that you don't serve malware from these links.

Comment: Your explanation is convincing. Any other thoughts from anyone else for my website [9o9.in](http://9o9.in)?